# How to reuse page_source in Appium driver queries

Tags: webdriver, appium, python-appium

I have checkForKnownExceptionScreens() function to check for all the known popup windows.

The checkForKnownExceptionScreens() performs multiple queries using Appium webdriver on various id strings. For example, it invokes multiple driver.find_elements_by_id()  with different ids, it also invokes driver.find_elements_by_class_name() with different class name etc. 
This results in making multiple calls to the Appium server thus to the mobile device.

To make the function efficient, I want to get get the page source XML content through driver.page_source and use the XML content within my function.

Is there a way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to parse that xml to find if it really contains what you need.

Easier solution would be to create a list of elements on your view and iterate trough it to see if it contains your element.

Sample (java) code:

```
List<AndroidElement> elementsList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
        for(AndroidElement element : elementsList){
//            check if it's your element
        }
```